# struct member value zero but macro checking if it's zero returns 0, why?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, macros, gdb, arm64

in arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable-types.h

```
typedef struct { pgdval_t pgd; } pgd_t;
#define pgd_val(x)  ((x).pgd)
#define __pgd(x)    ((pgd_t) { (x) } )
```

And in arch/arm64/include/asm/pgtable.h,

```
#define pgd_none(pgd)       (!pgd_val(pgd))
```

I was in arch/arm64/mm/mmu.c during the debug using qemu and gdb, it read pgd entry in addr pgdp and if it's empty, fills it with pointer to bm_pud.

```
void __init early_fixmap_init(void)
{
    pgd_t *pgdp, pgd;
    pud_t *pudp;
    pmd_t *pmdp;
    unsigned long addr = FIXADDR_START;

    pgdp = pgd_offset_k(addr);
    pgd = READ_ONCE(*pgdp);
    if (CONFIG_PGTABLE_LEVELS > 3 &&
        !(pgd_none(pgd) || pgd_page_paddr(pgd) == __pa_symbol(bm_pud))) {
        /*
         * We only end up here if the kernel mapping and the fixmap
         * share the top level pgd entry, which should only happen on
         * 16k/4 levels configurations.
         */
        BUG_ON(!IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_ARM64_16K_PAGES));
        pudp = pud_offset_kimg(pgdp, addr);
    } else {
        if (pgd_none(pgd))         <====== here!!
            __pgd_populate(pgdp, __pa_symbol(bm_pud), PUD_TYPE_TABLE);
        pudp = fixmap_pud(addr);
    }
```

When gdb is at the line marked with `<=== here!!` above,

```
(gdb) p pgd
$4 = {pgd = 0x0}
(gdb) p pgd_none(pgd)
$5 = 0x0
```

The pgd value is 0, but the pgd_none output is also 0 when it should be 1(true) and it skipps the __pgd_populate function. What is wrong here?

Comment: What does `(gdb) info func pgd_none` say? I suspect you are calling a function, not the macro you are intending to "call".

Comment: Oh,  info func pgd_none says `All functions matching regular expression "pgd_none":
File ./include/asm-generic/pgtable-nop4d-hack.h:
27: static int pgd_none(pgd_t);
`  so I figure pgd_none is not what I think it is! and this actually used function always returns 0. That was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @EmployedRussian I learned about using `info` command for function. Why don't you make your comment and answer so I can pick it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `(gdb) info func pgd_none` say?

I suspect you are calling a function, not the macro you are intending to "call".

In fact, I am not sure GDB is even *capable* of evaluating a macro.

**Update:**

As ssbssa@ noted, GDB is [documented](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html) to support macro evaluation, and will do that automatically if the source is compiled with `-g3`.

However, there is a bug in GDB (current as of version `12.0.50.20220221-git`) which prevents this from working, unless the code is compiled with `-gdwarf-4`.

Here is a trivial test:

```
#define FOO(x) (x - 42)

int main()
{
  int x = 42;
  return FOO(x);
}
```

Compile with `gcc -g3 foo.c -gdwarf-4`.

```
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x112d: file foo.c, line 5.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:5
5         int x = 42;
(gdb) n
6         return FOO(x);
(gdb) p FOO(1)
$1 = -41
```

**Update 2:**

From ssbssa@: this should work now with dwarf-5 in gdb-13 (see [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29606)).

Comment: `info func pgd_none` showed I was using another function which always returns 0. That was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, gdb can [evaluate macros](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Macros.html), if you add the macro debug information when [compiling](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Compilation.html) (with `-g3`).

Comment: @ssbssa or so the documentation claims. A trivial example I tried resulted in `No symbol "FOO" in current context.` using GDB-10.0 and current trunk, so I am still not sure it _can_ do that.

Comment: @EmployedRussian The program needs to be running, and you have to be at a location where the macro is visible. But there seems to be a bug in gdb when you use dwarf-5, so if you're using that, you might need to try again with dwarf-4.

Comment: Update: this should work now with dwarf-5 in gdb-13 (see [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29606)).